# jQuery mousemove doesn't get fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

**Here's a Codepen**
http://cdpn.io/CnwtL

I'm trying to mimic/improve the mouse move based scroll that you can find here:
http://www.ciena.com/resources/posters/Packet-Optical-Convergence-Infographic.html
(you have to click for the infographic to see what I'm talking about).

The problem right now is that when the mousemove event doesn't seem to be firing. Any idea why?

Comment: Seems to be firing to me...my console logged the `hello` response.

Comment: What browser[s]? You need to supply that important detail

Comment: This works on Chrome's latest stable build. What browser are you using that this isn't working in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
var parentOffset = parent.offset.left;
```

For this

```
var parentOffset = parent.offset().left;
```

And see this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBfJd)**